# How can I redraw a canvas dashboard every 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I redraw a canvas every 5 minutes? I drew an arc dashboard on canvas, but when I redraw it, my canvas ends up smudgy.

I need that this dashboard redraws with random values every 5 minutes.

How can I do this?

```js
function dashboards() {
    var porcent= 80;// it is variable %
    // start o dashboard
    var canvas = document.getElementById("dash");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var graus = (porcent * 360) / 100; // convert porcent to degree
    var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * graus;// convert degree to radius

    // start back grey 
    var canvas_fundo = document.getElementById('dash');
    var ctx_fundo = canvas_fundo.getContext('2d');
    var graus_fundo = 360 //  degree
    var radians_fundo = (Math.PI / 180) * graus_fundo;// convert degree to radius

    ctx_fundo.strokeStyle = '#D3D3D3';// color border grey
    ctx_fundo.beginPath();// start draw
    ctx_fundo.lineWidth = 20;// width border
    ctx_fundo.arc(110, 110, 95, 0, radians_fundo, false);// do circle
    ctx_fundo.stroke();// do border
    //end back grey

    if (porcent <= 40) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';// color border red
    } else if ((porcent > 40) && (porcent < 70)) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFD700';// color border yellow
    } else {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#32CD32';// color border green
    }
    ctx.beginPath();// start draw
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;// width border
    ctx.arc(110, 110, 95, 0, radians, false);// do circle
    ctx.stroke();// do border

    ctx.font = '28px arial';// font text
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';// position
    ctx.fillText(porcent.toFixed(1) + '%', 112, 120);// text and your possition


    // end dashboard
    }
    dashboards();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <canvas id="dash" height="300"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

[image]

it is erased

Comment: What do you mean by smudgy? Can we see a picture?

Comment: why redraw, something changes?

Comment: zednat, redraw be erased

Comment: The code you've shared does not produce the result you say it does. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that does recreate the situation you have.

Comment: the image is blurred but my code is not because the code is not redrawing, but if I create a setinterval function my dashboard is like the image that was added in the body of the question.

Comment: ... Then it's an easy edit for you to make; add the `setInterval` to your code, along with the random percentage or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your code, add interval of 5sec, just change the time interval to your desired minutes, add a function that generates random int then pass it you dashboads function, I also add ctx.clearReact() to clear the text percentage at the center of canvas. See the code below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <canvas id="dash" height="300"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
<script>
function dashboards(percent) {
    var porcent= percent;// it is variable %
    var ctx = null;
    // start o dashboard
    var canvas = document.getElementById("dash");
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear the canvas
    var graus = (porcent * 360) / 100; // convert porcent to degree
    var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * graus;// convert degree to radius

    // start back grey
    var canvas_fundo = document.getElementById('dash');
    var ctx_fundo = canvas_fundo.getContext('2d');
    var graus_fundo = 360 //  degree
    var radians_fundo = (Math.PI / 180) * graus_fundo;// convert degree to radius

    ctx_fundo.strokeStyle = '#D3D3D3';// color border grey
    ctx_fundo.beginPath();// start draw
    ctx_fundo.lineWidth = 20;// width border
    ctx_fundo.arc(110, 110, 95, 0, radians_fundo, false);// do circle
    ctx_fundo.stroke();// do border
    //end back grey

    if (porcent <= 40) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';// color border red
    } else if ((porcent > 40) && (porcent < 70)) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFD700';// color border yellow
    } else {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#32CD32';// color border green
    }
    ctx.beginPath();// start draw
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;// width border
    ctx.arc(110, 110, 95, 0, radians, false);// do circle
    ctx.stroke();// do border

    ctx.font = '28px arial';// font text
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';// position
    //ctx.clearRect(50, 50, 112, 120); //clear text in your position
    ctx.fillText(porcent.toFixed(1) + '%', 112, 120);// text and your possition

    // end dashboard
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

setInterval(function () {
  dashboards(getRandomInt(1, 100));
}, 5000);

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Renan, hope this will help, you may test this and see if this is what you need.

Comment: that is a good solution, however, keep in wind that the outer circle will still looks "blurred" as the semi transparent pixels of the circle will be aliased

Comment: in that case we just have to clear the canvas before anything else be done or rendered, I will modify this, the solution is simple, just move the ctx.clearRect(50, 50, 112, 120); under the ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); then change the coordinates and passed the width and height of the canva.

Comment: yeah, i was just pointing this to you since OP doesn't want to understand ;)

Comment: I will modify this to meet the said "blurred", and I believe this is what you need. @Renan Osorio

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! really solved my problem. Thank you for your patience and I'm sorry for my English I'm still learning.

Comment: Just change the interval value of 5000 ms to 300000 ms that is equivalent to 5 minutes, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

add a canvas clear at the start of your dashboard function, and add the `porcent` variable as this function argument

then you can just call `dashboard(Math.random() * 100)` every 5 minutes with a setInterval

Comment: so he asked for function arguments but he can already do canvas stuff?

Comment: i think what he was missing was to clear the canvas as the differents percentages overlap, but i also pointed him the interval and argument as the question was unclear to me

Comment: Neil, if i do it, my canvas will be erased

Comment: yes, it will be erased and immediatly reprinted with new values, i may be misunderstanding your question then

Comment: @RenanOsorio also, it looks blurred because all your "80%" have semi-transparent pixels on the side, wich looks less transparent when they overlap, thus adding the need of a canvas clear each time, right before redrawing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your canvas each time you redraw to it. Otherwise, what was here before just stay there. Add:

`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

To your function.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect)